# Using foreign keyboard without needing to press Alt Gr

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Ok, so I just installed my local language Lithuanian (US, with Lithuanian letters). When I used Ubuntu a few years ago and on Windows, this keyboard replaces 1234567 with my local letter, now for some reason I HAVE to hold down <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> in order to switch from 12345 to my local letters.

I am using two keyboards and have no problems switching between them when I need EN (US) and my local. I don't hold any <kbd>Alt-GR</kbd>. How can I turn off the need to click <kbd>Alt-gr</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Lithuanian* keyboard layout instead of *Lithuanian (US, with Lithuanian letters)*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried all layouts. The one you mentioned also should have layout as I described (Show Keyboard layout button proves that), but in Ubuntu it's even worse, because now even with Alt Gr I can't use letter in numbers section. There is layouts such as IBM layout that has working letter without click Alt Gr, but they are in extremely uncomfortable positions.

Comment: @enigmq: There must be some misunderstanding here. If I select _Lithuanian_, pressing the number keys without <AltGr> results in various letters with diacritics (which I assume are useful when typing your language). With that layout <AltGr> is used to type the numbers, i.e. it works the opposite way compared to _Lithuanian (US, with Lithuanian letters)_.

Comment: Not in my case. Maybe it has something to do with settings? Probably I will get used to using <AltGr> after a week or so, but I am just curious.

Comment: @enigmq: Let's check which layout you are using. Switch to Lithuanian and then show us the output of this command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources`

Comment: gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources -> Lithuanian (US, with Lithuanian letters) output: [('xkb', 'lt+us'), ('xkb', 'lt'), ('xkb', 'us')]
And when using simply Lithuanian output: [('xkb', 'lt'), ('xkb', 'lt+us'), ('xkb', 'us')]

Comment: @enigmq: Looks right. Then I don't understand why Lithuanian doesn't work the same way for you as it does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here we go 25 days later. My monitors suddenly shut down. Restarting computer didn't help, so I had to completely turn it off and on (hard reset). Now ubuntu booted normally. A lot of problems with resolution seems to be fixed AND surprise, surprise keyboard started to work as it should!